# what is bootstrap-server in kafka config?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have just started learning kafka and continuously I am coming across a term `bootstrap-server`.

Which server does it represent in my kafka cluster?

Comment: Hey, great that you're learning Kafka. You'd find a ton of the answers to your questions in "Kafka, the Definitive Guide", which you can get for free here: http://cnfl.io/book-bundle

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is the url of one of the Kafka brokers which you give to fetch the initial metadata about your Kafka cluster.
The metadata consists of the topics, their partitions, the leader brokers for those partitions etc.
Depending upon this metadata your producer or consumer produces or consumes the data.

You can have multiple bootstrap-servers in your producer or consumer configuration. So that if one of the broker is not accessible, then it falls back to other.

Answer (score 57):

We know that a kafka cluster can have 100s or 1000nds of brokers (kafka servers). But how do we tell clients (producers or consumers) to which to connect? Should we specify all 1000nds of kafka brokers in the configuration of clients? no, that would be troublesome and the list will be very lengthy. Instead what we can do is, take two to three brokers and consider them as bootstrap servers where a client initially connects. And then depending on alive or spacing, those brokers will point to a good kafka broker.

So `bootstrap.servers` is a configuration we place within clients, which is a comma-separated list of host and port pairs that are the addresses of the Kafka brokers in a "bootstrap" Kafka cluster that a Kafka client connects to initially to bootstrap itself.

A host and port pair uses : as the separator.

```
localhost:9092
localhost:9092,another.host:9092
```

So as mentioned, `bootstrap.servers` provides the initial hosts that act as the starting point for a Kafka client to discover the full set of alive servers in the cluster.

Special Notes:

- Since these servers are just used for the initial connection to discover the full cluster membership (which may change dynamically), this list does not have to contain the full set of servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is down).
- Clients (producers or consumers) make use of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified in bootstrap.servers for bootstrapping.

Answer (score 10):

> bootstrap.servers is a comma-separated list of host and port pairs that are the addresses of the Kafka brokers in a "bootstrap" Kafka cluster that a Kafka client connects to initially to bootstrap itself.

Kafka broker

> A Kafka cluster is made up of multiple Kafka Brokers. Each Kafka Broker has a unique ID (number). Kafka Brokers contain topic log partitions. Connecting to one broker bootstraps a client to the entire Kafka cluster. For failover, you want to start with at least three to five brokers. A Kafka cluster can have, 10, 100, or 1,000 brokers in a cluster if needed.

more information: check [this](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture/index.html), [official doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)